# fscanf changing file position to a negative value

Tags: c, file, scanf, ftell

I have code for processing a file having numbers at the beginning, which I have to read, and then letters. I need to print letters with index corresponding to the numbers at the beginning of the file, where the index is interpreted as position from the beginning of the file.
For example, if the first number in the file is 10 then I need to print the tenth character of the file.

The problem is that when I use `fscanf`, after the first use, `ftell` gives a negative index of exactly -7 (where is having value -7). This makes the program stop on processing that letter, on account of the attempt to read that letter with `scanf` returning 0. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char letter;
    int num;
    long where;
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("chance.txt","r")) == NULL) {
        printf("File corrupted");
        return 1;
    }

    rewind(fp);
    while (fscanf(fp,"%d",&num) == 1) {
        where = ftell(fp);
        fseek(fp,num,SEEK_SET);
        letter = (char)fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c", letter);
        fseek(fp,where,SEEK_SET);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The file could look like this

```
30 23 42
32
"Some text"
```

The whole file will never be shorter than the biggest index.

Comment: What is the contents of the file you try to read? Please show us an example of actual contents. For example, are the numbers and letters on different lines?

Comment: and what output do you expect?

Comment: Also note that `fscanf(fp, "%d", num)` will return `0` when it comes to anything that can't be parsed as an `int` value. That means you could have two consecutive loops: One to read the numbers; And if there's no error or `EOF`, a second loop to read the characters. If I understand the description of your file correctly.

Comment: I don't understand the use of `fseek(fp,where,SEEK_SET);`.  Shouldn't you instead be progressing the file pointer beyond the position of the char after the number?

Comment: Or if it's always a number followed by a character, then use `"%d %c"` as the format?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i edited it, the file will always have only numbers at the beginning and then text, numbers are positions of the chars from the beginning of the file

Comment: You could open the file two times: One for reading the numbers, and one for seeking and reading characters. Then you don't have to get and reset the position every time. Just seek and read from the second "file".

Comment: (a) To use `fseek` to move to arbitrary positions in a file, the stream should be opened as binary, with `"rb"`, not as text, with `"r"`. (b) You say `ftell` returns −7 but you do not say how you know this or show any evidence. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: FYI, `letter` should be `unsigned char` or `int`. `fgetc` returns either EOF or the value of the next character in a stream as an `unsigned char` value. An `int` is needed to hold the possibilities. If it can be taken that `EOF` is never returned, then an `unsigned char` can be used. A `char` should not be used because it can be signed, and the conversion from an `unsigned char` value to a signed `char` value would be implementation-defined.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the problem is i cant store the data anywhere it needs to be done dynamically

Comment: Cannot reproduce after putting together a test file that conforms to the spec (yours does not). The position from `ftell` is never negative and the output is correct.

Comment: With the two-file solution there's no need to store anything. Just one loop reading the numbers from the first file, like you have now. Then seek and read characters using the second file inside the loop, still very much similar to what you're doing now.

Comment: Are you doing this on a system that distinguishes text and binary streams, such as Windows, or on a system where all streams are binary streams, such as Unix?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That is two streams, one file. In C, the “connection” to a file is a stream. A file is something outside C, such as a disk file.

Comment: The sample input file give in the question does not appear to satisfy the requirement that the whole file be at least as long as the largest index expressed in it.

Comment: Your program works as expected for me on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Your program compiles cleanly for me, unmodified, on Linux, and it behaves there exactly as you describe it should.  I could not use **the input file provided in the question** for testing, however, because it **does not satisfy the requirement that the length of the file be at least as great as the largest index within**.  (And actually, the length needs to *exceed* the largest index, even if only by 1 byte, because as the program is using them, the indexes are zero-based.)

If, in your environment, the program presented misbehaves when processing a valid input file, then that most likely arises from the fact that **you open the file as a text stream, but use file-positioning functions in a way that is not wholly defined for text streams**.  POSIX systems do not distinguish between text and binary streams, but some other systems do, with Windows being a prime example.

Consider this code:

> ```
>         where = ftell(fp);
>         fseek(fp,num,SEEK_SET);
>         letter = (char)fgetc(fp);
>         printf("%c", letter);
>         fseek(fp,where,SEEK_SET);
> ```

Given `fp` referring to a text stream, the `ftell` is fine, and the `fseek(fp,where,SEEK_SET)` is also fine: as long as the stream is seekable in the first place, you can use `fseek` with `SEEK_SET` to reposition it to a point that was previously recorded via `ftell()`.  However, C does not define the meaning of seeking to an arbitrary position in a text stream, so `fseek(fp,num,SEEK_SET)` *is not* fine.  That will work as intended on Linux (for example), but not necessarily on some other systems.

One solution would be:

1. Open the file as a binary stream:

   ```
       if ((fp = fopen("chance.txt", "rb")) == NULL) {
   ```

   (note open mode `"rb"` instead of `"r"`).
2. Ensure that the file has single-byte line terminators (at least if it is supposed to yield the same output on Windows as on Linux).

Additionally, even though it may seem tedious, it is wise to check the return values of *all* function calls that may indicate errors that way, so as to recognize those error signals if they come, and take appropriate action.  Often that's just to report the nature of the error and perhaps its location, then terminate.  You missed some.  I'm not sure whether checking those would have given you useful information, but it might have done.

Side note: it is pointless (but not inherently wrong) to `rewind()` a file immediately after opening it.